# How to simply integral a function written in Sympy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Through using the ways and obtaining help from Stackoverflow users, I could find half of the solution and I need to complete it.
Through using Sympy I could produce my function parametrically and it became 100 different items similar to `0.03149536*exp(-4.56*s)*sin(2.33*s) 0.03446408*exp(-4.56*s)*sin(2.33*s)`. By using `f = lambdify(s,f)` I converted it to a NumPy function and I needed to do integral of `in the different` s`that I already have. The upper limit of the integral is a constant value and the lower limit must be done through a`for loop`.

---

When I try to do, I get some error which I post below. The code that I wrote is below, but for being a reproducible question I have to put a generated data. `TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational`

```
from sympy import exp, sin, symbols, integrate, lambdify
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

S = np.linspace(0,1000,100)
C = np.linspace(0,1,100)

s, t = symbols('s t')
lanr = -4.56
lani = -2.33
ID = S[-1]
result=[]
f = C * exp(lanr * s) * sin (lani * s)
f = lambdify(s,f)
#vff = np.vectorize(f)
for i in (S):
    I = integrate.quad(f,s,(i,ID))
    result.append(I)
print(result)
```

---

***EDIT***

1. I tried to do the same without having`Sympy` by using just `Scipy` and wrote the code below and again I could not solve the problem.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

lanr = -6.55
lani = -4.22

def integrand(c,s):
    return c *  np.exp(lanr * s) * np.sin (lani * s)



def self_integrate(c,s):
    return quad(integrand,s,1003,1200)

import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('1-100.csv',sep="\s+",header=None)
s = np.linspace(0,1000,100)
c = np.linspace(0,1,100)
ID = s[-1]
for i in s:
    
    I = self_integrate(integrand,c,s)
    print(I)
```

and I got this `TypeError: self_integrate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: It looks like you could integrate this symbolically with sympy's integrate function rather than using lambdify and scipy.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin you're right. I could but I wouldn't like since, in the end, I need to have a list of numbers which is the `result`. Now I do not know how to do that.

Comment: You can substitute values after integrating

Comment: @OscarBenjamin does not integrate since it thinks that it is still in `Sympy` format, Even I tried a number of times but I could not solve it.

Comment: Don't mix sympy and scipy like this until you are sure you know what you are doing. This problem can be solved using either only sympy or only scipy. You do not gain anything in this example by mixing them.

Comment: Don't put array `C` in the sympy function.

Comment: What's `s` the sympy variable doing in the `quad` call?  And the tuple argument?  Traceback please!

Comment: @hpaulj I need to do integral of `s` in a `for` loop between a constant upper limit of s which is `ID` and lower limit of s which is `i` that changes in every cycle.  In terms of `c` the function has a unique value of `c` in every loop. So I had to put it.

Comment: But you didn't read the `quad` docs!

Comment: @hpaulj I did but you're right I have to be more careful of details. I will do again and hope to find the final result. BTW thanks

Comment: `quad` integrates over the first argument of the function.  Any other arguments are passed in the `args` tuple.  If you are integrating over `s`, use `integrand(s,c)`, and pass `c` as `args=(c,)`.  `quad` does not take a integration symbol.  Stop trying to get multiple answers and focus on getting just one `quad` call right.

Comment: @hpaulj I promise that it is my last question. For upper and lower bound of the integral, Am I correct if I write this `quad(integrand,s,s[i],ID,args=(c,))`? I want to do integral through a for loop from the first element of `s` until the `ID`. Sorry for my disturbing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to integrate over `s`, and use `c` as a fixed parameter (for a given `quad` call), define:

```
In [198]: lanr = 1
     ...: lani = 2
     ...: def integrand(s, c):
     ...:     return c *  np.exp(lanr * s) * np.sin (lani * s)
     ...:
```

test it by itself:

```
In [199]: integrand(10,1.23)
Out[199]: 24734.0175253505
```

and test it in `quad`:

```
In [200]: quad(integrand, 0, 10, args=(1.23,))
Out[200]: (524.9015616747192, 3.381048596651226e-08)
```

doing the same for a range of `c` values:

```
In [201]: alist = []
     ...: for c in range(0,10):
     ...:     x,y = quad(integrand, 0, 10, args=(c,))
     ...:     alist.append(x)
     ...: 
In [202]: alist
Out[202]: 
[0.0,
 426.74923713391905,
 853.4984742678381,
 1280.2477114017531,
 1706.9969485356762,
 2133.7461856695877,
 2560.4954228035062,
 2987.244659937424,
 3413.9938970713524,
 3840.743134205258]
```

From the `quad` docs:

```
quad(func, a, b, args=(),...)

func : {function, scipy.LowLevelCallable}
    A Python function or method to integrate. If `func` takes many
    arguments, it is integrated along the axis corresponding to the
    first argument.
```

and an example:

```
>>> f = lambda x,a : a*x
>>> y, err = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1, args=(1,))
```

The docs are a bit long, but the basics should be straight forward.

I was tempted to say you were stuck on the `sympy` calling pattern, but the second argument for that is either the integration symbol, or a tuple.

```
>>> integrate(log(x), (x, 1, a))
a*log(a) - a + 1
```

So I'm puzzled as to why you were stuck on using

```
quad(integrand,s,1003,1200)
```

The `s`, whether a sympy variable or a linspace array does not make sense.

Comment: Found it absolutely my solution, however, I loved your attitude towards StackOverflow. To motivate users to solve the problem by hints and comments to read the docs deeply, rather than just writing the answer.